# how to display particular fields in form Symfony 2.6

Tags: forms, symfony

I need display particular fields in form in Symfony 2.6. I use a class Form. I have the folowing fields: name, email, message, send, recet. I need display all of them except recet .I try like this:

```
                 {{form_start(form)}}
                    {{ form_errors(form) }}
                    {{form_row(form.name)}}
                    {{form_row(form.email)}}
                    {{form_row(form.message)}}
                {{form_end(form)}}
```

But, it's displaying all fields in form, it is not what I want. Even if i leave only `{{form_start(form)}}` and  `{{form_end(form)}}` - its display all fields. Can someone help me wit this problem?

Answer (score 0):

remove form_end, just close form with HTML

```
</form>
```

but then you must handle CSRF token generation by adding:
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}

```
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
```

or try setting field you do not want to show using:

```
{% do form.recet.setRendered %}
```

but probably best way is not to add this field in the first place, rather than hiding it, by form options or event listeners depending on some criterias

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to remove the field from the form type. If you only remove it from the view, it may be interpreted as a blank submission for that field and delete existing data.

If you only use the form in one place, then just remove the field from the type. If you use it in multiple places, then you can selectively remove the field in a `FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA` event listener.